# Таск удаления папки для gulp не работает

Tags: javascript, gulp

Делал сборку gulp по видеоуроку из Youtube, дошёл до таска удаления папок, сделал все как в уроке, один в один, у ютубера работает у меня нет, в чём причина? при вызове gulp clear выдает ошибку.[image: gulpfile.js]

Comment: Не работает только таск удаления? Судя по ошибке у вас в импортах проблема

Comment: HaZcker, да не работает только таск удаления. А какая проблема может быть в импортах?

Answer (score 0):

Плагин *del* обновился до версии 7.0.0 и его можно импортировать только через импорты. Варианта два, переходить везде на импорты или устанавливать пакет версии 6.1.1:

```
npm i -D del@6.1.1
```

Это последняя версия, где можно было установить через `require`.